# Combine multiple lists in python to single list

Tags: python, list

```
def combine_lists(lt1, lt2):
    if lt1[0] and lt2[0]:
        lt = [lt1, lt2]
    elif lt1[0] and not lt2[0]:
        lt = [lt1]
    elif not lt1[0] and lt2[0]:
        lt = [lt2]
    elif not lt1[0] and not lt2[0]:
        lt = [None, None]

    return lt
```

The function above combines 2 lists into a single list. E.g. `lt1` could be somthing like `['a', 'b']`

What is the most pythonic way to extend this from just 2 input parameters to an arbitrary number of lists as input. The output should still be a list of lists

--EDIT

The expected answer for lt1 = [1, 2, 3], lt2=[4, 5, 6] should be [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

Comment: Can you please give example input *and output*? So what is `lt1`, `lt2`, and what should `lt` be in the end?

Comment: Also, explain the conditions you are making. What is the goal of this function exactly? Are you simply just trying to do `[1, 2, 3]` + `[4, 5, 6]` = `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`? or `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`?

Comment: If you're trying to check if a list is empty with ``not lt2[0]`` / ``not lt1[0]`` then you'll be up for a surprise, as this will give you an Exception. Even more so if you intend to check if the list is ``None`` instead of empty.

Comment: thanks all, the expected answer for [1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6] should be [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

Comment: What's the expected output for `combine([0], [1])`, `combine([], [])` and `combine([1], [0], [2])`?

Comment: @Rawing, expected output would be `[[0], [1]]`; `[[], []]`; `[[1], [0], [2]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use list comprehension here, and let it work for an *arbitrary* number of arguments using `*args`:

```
def combine_lists(*args):
    return [lt if lt[0] else None for lt in args]
```

The code works as follows, by using list comprehesion, we will iterate over the `args`, a tuple of the unnamed arguments with which `combine_lists` was called. For each of these lists `lt`, we check `if lt[0]` if that is the case, then we add `lt` to the list, otherwise we add `None`.

Note that this program can **raise an error**: in case one of the `lt`s **can not be indexed**, or **has no element at index 0**. So it is quite unsafe.

You can - by altering the semantics slighly - prevent this from happening: if we are dealing with an empty list, then we add that list in the following example:

```
def combine_lists(*args):
    return [lt if not lt or lt[0] else None for lt in args]
```

This will work given all objects are lists, tuples, etc.

Comment: Hm, how about `[lt if not lt else lt if lt[0] else None for lt in args]`. As far as I can tell, OP wants `None` if the first element is falsy, but wants an empty list in case of an empty list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: this indeed solves the matter, given all elements are `lists`. A generic object for instance, has a truthiness that is `True`, but has no `object[0]`.

Comment: Ah, better with the `or` for sure.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question, you want something like this:

```
>>> def combine(*args):
...     return list(args)
... 
>>> print combine([1,2,3], ['a','b','c'], [True, False])
[[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [True, False]]
```

So, we're using [positional arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) from `args` (which are stored in a `tuple`) and converting them to a list. It works for any number of arguments, and it'll happily combine anything (not just lists) into a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` with multiple arguments `*args` and return a `map object` like this example:

```
def combine_list(*args):
    return map(list, args)


final = list(combine(['a','b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']))
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
```

Comment: OP stated ``The output should still be a list of lists``.

Comment: Humm ok i missed that part. i'm updating my answer so. Thanks for pointing it

Comment: Better wait until OP specifies input values and the desired output ;)

Comment: Pendantic note: `map` is not a generator.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga please explain more ? thanks

Comment: You say you can use `map` and return a generator. But that isn't what you are returning. You are returning a `map` object, which is not a generator.

Comment: Yes you're right ! Thanks. It's a map object.

Answer (score 1):

```
    def combine_lists(lt1, lt2):
       lt = []
       lt.append(lt1)
       lt.append(lt2)
       return lt
```

You can simply do this. It will give you the list of the two lists you have.